# $parse:syntax error in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have below code on Html page.

```
<div class="thumbnail" ng-show="location.name" ng-repeat="location in vm.locationList">
<div class="name"><strong>Name:</strong> {{location.name}}<div>
```

I get location info from `ng-repeat="location in vm.locationList"`. My code is running.It is writing Html page. But I see some error on console page.I have checked all javascript code but I have never seen any error.Only in console page, error message is seen.
My error message is

```
[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ',' is an unexpected token at column 6 of the expression [Paris, Fransa] starting at [, Fransa].
```

Do you have any idea?

Comment: its difficult to say from just one line of code what is the issue , Could you provide more code from ng-repeat and also give your locationList .

Comment: Kindly provide more code. it's not enough to understand the issue . please provide code related with `expression [Paris, Fransa] starting at [, Fransa].`

Comment: Thank you very much @vertika .I checked ng-repeat section.I changed code like this `ng-show="vm.locationList.length"`.Right now, It is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, `[, Fransa]` shows that 0th index element of your array is empty.

Comment: If you have any doubt's or thought's, then please post as a comment instead of  post answer :)